# Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json and type int

Tags: java, junit

I got a main project, that I have to test now...
I made a second project for that, in that project, I pasted the interfaces and entities from the main project, and now I made a simple jUnit test case...
Looks like this:

```
public class TestLogin {

String path = "http://localhost:8080/rest/dss"; //thats the right path...
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
ResteasyWebTarget rtarget = client.target(path);
DssRest rest = rtarget.proxy(DssRest.class);

@Test
public void test() {
    assert(rest.login(null, "Test", "Test") != -1);
}

}
```

DssRest, interface

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/login/{userName}/{password}")
int login(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @PathParam("userName") String userName,
        @PathParam("password") String password);
```

from there I go to the DssBean, where the function is that I wanna test

```
@Override
public int login(HttpServletRequest req, String userName, String password) {
    ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
    ResteasyWebTarget rtarget = client.target(".../rest/mw"); //real path
    MWRest rest = rtarget.proxy(MWRest.class);
    int userId = rest.login(userName, password);
    ...
    return userId; //it always is > -1

}
```

From there, I call the MWRest, an interface of my second project...and that project has the same function, which returns an INT, 12 for exemple...

now....to test that, made a junit test suite

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({TestLogin.class})
public class AllTests {

}
```

Before I run it, I made sure, the 2 projects I need to test are running...
Then I run the suite, as jUnit test, and on the JUnit console, there is this error, which I simply cannot figure out.

I hope you can help....thx

```
javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json and type int
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.extractResult(ClientInvocation.java:140)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.extractors.BodyEntityExtractor.extractEntity(BodyEntityExtractor.java:58)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:104)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:62)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.login(Unknown Source)
at test.dss.TestLogin.test(TestLogin.java:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json and type int
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientReaderInterceptorContext.throwReaderNotFound(ClientReaderInterceptorContext.java:39)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.getReader(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:73)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:50)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:59)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:53)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.readFrom(ClientResponse.java:248)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:181)
at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.readEntity(BuiltResponse.java:211)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.extractResult(ClientInvocation.java:104)
... 36 more
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Take a look at your pom whether you've added "resteasy-jackson-provider" dependency.

Comment: i dont have maven nor pom

Comment: You should. Anyways, check whether you have resteasy-jackson-provider.jar in your classpath.

Comment: I also have the  resteasy-jackson-provider.jar